# Where is the cron from this Chef recipe?

Tags: cron, chef, opsworks

I have added, and successfully setup and deploy an instance with this recipe:

`cron "haproxy_log" do
  command "logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy"
  minute '15'
end`

But when I look at `/etc/crontab` I don't see it being there. Where does the cron chef puts its cron jobs?

When I do `sudo crontab -u root -l` I see my job. But how come I can't see it in `/etc/crontab`?

The cron doesn't run, but I am able to run the command manually by doing:
`sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy` - Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2):

The crontab you see with `sudo crontab -u root -l` is a normal user **crontab for user `root`**, located in:

- `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` (Debian, Ubuntu, HP-UX, SGI IRIX)
- `/var/spool/cron/root` (CentOS, RedHat, RHEL, Fedora, IBM AIX and company)
- `/var/cron/tabs/root` (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD)
- `/usr/lib/cron/tabs/root` (Mac OS X)

These files should not be edited directly, but always with the `crontab` command.

The commands on **`root`'s crontab** are also always run as `root`, i.e.

- they have the normal `m h dom mon dow command` syntax
- while in the **system-wide** `/etc/crontab` and in `/etc/cron.d/*` you must also specify the user:

  ```
  # /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
  # Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
  # command to install the new version when you edit this file
  # and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
  # that none of the other crontabs do.

  # m h dom mon dow user  command
  ```

A hint towards this is also hidden inside Chef's Cookbook Reference, [Resource `cron`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cron.html):

> The **cron** resource requires access to a `crontab` program, typically cron.
>
> **Warning:** 
>   The **cron** resource should only be used to modify an entry in a
>   crontab file. Use the **cookbook_file** or **template** resources to add a
>   crontab file to the cron.d directory. The `cron_d` lightweight resource
>   (found in the [cron](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/cron) cookbook) is another option for managing crontab
>   files.

Comment: Esa, thanks a lot for the answer. It's still not clear to me. The command didn't run through the cron, but I am able to manually run `sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy`.

What do you think is going on? I basically want to run that command on an hourly basis, using a chef recipe to set it in the instance.

Comment: If you saw your cronjob on `crontab -l`, it should be in place despite it's not on system-wide cron. Could you add the output of your `contab -u root -l`?

Comment: When running `crontab -l` as my user, I don't see any. When running `sudo crontab -u root -l` I see: `# Chef Name: haproxy_log
15 * * * * logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy`

Comment: And probably there is a new-line before `15 * ...`, otherwise it would be commented out... But Chef wouldn't do that.

Comment: Sorry Esa, I don't understand. I think it's added properly into root's crontab, but I don't know why is not running. How can I triage this?

Comment: See from your syslog whether the command gets run or not. You could also add your address in `MAIL=` in the beginning of the crontab to get command output mailed to you for further debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59013/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-esa-jokinen).

Answer (score 1):

On Unix platforms excluding AIX and Solaris, Chef creates a tempfile using the typical crontab syntax, then feeding it to the `/usr/bin/crontab` command ([Source](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/a2890be2422453dee593ffb1f5eb6a49271c83be/lib/chef/provider/cron/unix.rb#L56)).

Depending on your OS/distribution, the location varies by the `cron` implementation. On Debian/Ubuntu for example (`man 8 cron`):

> cron  searches  its  spool area (/var/spool/cron/crontabs) for
>   crontab files (which are named after accounts in /etc/passwd);
>   crontabs found are loaded into memory.  Note that crontabs in this
>   directory should not be accessed directly - the crontab command should
>   be used to access and update them.
>
> cron also reads /etc/crontab, which is in a slightly different format (see crontab(5)).  In Debian, the content of /etc/crontab is
>   predefined to run programs under /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily,
>   /etc/cron.weekly and /etc/cron.monthly. This configuration is  spe‐
>   cific to Debian, see the note under DEBIAN SPECIFIC below.
>
> Additionally,  in Debian, cron reads the files in the /etc/cron.d directory.  cron treats the files in /etc/cron.d as in the
>   same way as the /etc/crontab file (they follow the special format of
>   that file, i.e. they include the user field). However, they are
>   independent of /etc/crontab: they do not, for example, inherit environment variable settings from it. This change is specific to
>   Debian see the note under DEBIAN SPECIFIC below.
>
> Like /etc/crontab, the files in the /etc/cron.d directory are monitored for changes. In general, the system administrator should not
>   use /etc/cron.d/, but use the standard system crontab /etc/crontab.

Long story short:

1. The destination is managed by `crontab` not chef
2. typical defaults for recent Debian/Ubuntu crons in 2017 are `/etc/cron.d/<filename>`

Comment: OP mentioned the job was in `crontab -l`. Therefore, there should be nothing wrong with the recipe. :)

Comment: I don't see it with `crontab -l`, just with `sudo crontab -u root -l`

Comment: That's just `crontab -l` for user `root`. There it is and there it should be.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not logged in as root, so if I do `crontab -l` I don't see anything

Comment: I only shortened it in a comment as everyone already knew the crontab we were talking about. We are still talking about the same thing. :)